# How to auto reduce font size if it is too long over fixed textbox in rdlc report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

My textbox have a some properties like these

```
   txtBox.Cangrow = False

   txtBox.CanShrink = False

   Uncheck allow height to increase and decrease.
```

This textbox use for display value which receive from dataset.
Sometime data is too long. 
So I need to know How to automatically decrease font size for matching with width of textbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to manually determine which font sizes are required for stings of a certain length.  You can then put an expression in the `Font` -> `FontSize` property as follows

```
=iif(len(Fields!myString.Value) > 20, "8pt", "10pt")
```

It's not possible to dynamically shrink the text to fit the textbox.

Comment: What possible if I check text is too long by a number of line?
example if it has multiple line, Font size  will be decreased.
Because of I need to show just single line in textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following worked best for me when dealing with dynamic numbers in a text field.

=iif(len(Fields!myString.Value.ToString) > 20, "8pt", "10pt")